# url path from categories in DetailView

Tags: django, django-urls

I use a DetailView to display all elements inside a category.

I am trying to get my category slugs as variables in urls. But I don't know how to make the link between categories and details.

So far when I click on one of the generated link in the Index.html such as http://localhost:8000/oneofthecategories, I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: author, category, category_id, id, title
```

Files:

```
#Models.py

class categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class details(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="detail")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

#Views.py

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = categories
    context_object_name = "list_categories"
    template_name='show/index.html'

class CategoryDetails(DetailView):
    model = details
    context_object_name = "detail"
    template_name = "show/categories.html"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

#Urls.py

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('<slug:slug>', views.CategoryDetails.as_view(), name='category_details'),
]

#Index.html

{% load staticfiles %}

<p>These is a list of categories</p>

{% for category in list_categories %}
    <div class="article">
    <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>

    {% for detail in category.categories.all %}
        <p> {{detail.title}} </p>
        <li><a href="{% url 'category_details' category.slug %}">URLS</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: *Where* do you get that error? Show the full traceback.

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are trying to do here. Your details model doesn't have a slug; in your index template you use the *category* slug for the link to the details page for some reason. Please explain what slug you want to use and what the details page should show.

Comment: Basically on one page I want to list my categories with the titles of object in each category plus a link to acces each individual categories that will detail the objects in those perticular categories. So I thaught I have to use a ListView to display my categories and a DetailView to get the details of the objects in each category. But I don't get how to link all this together...

Comment: So shouldn't DetailView have its model as `categories`, not `detail`?

Comment: Ok, so it works by taking categories as model and then using {% for x in detail.categories.all %}<p> {{x.title}} </p>{% endfor %} in the template. Thanks for help.